# Cannot invoke '-' with an argument list of type (CGFloat, CGFloat)

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
let startX = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(maxX + (quarterX*2))) - quarterX
```

Where *quarterX* is a CGFloat.

This line of code give the build error

> Cannot invoke '-' with an argument list of type (CGFloat, CGFloat)

Which just seems weird to me. What is at play here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arc4random_uniform` requires a `UInt32`, but you are passing a `CGFloat` (I presume maxX is of the same type). So you have to convert this expression:

```
maxX + quarterX * 2
```

to `UInt32`:

```
let startX = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxX + quarterX * 2))) - quarterX
```

Let me say that the error message is a bit misleading and completely useless :)

Comment: Ah yes. of course. That weird error message threw me of the trail so to speak.

Comment: I learnt that if a compiler message doesn't make any sense, then it's something else and usually a simple thing